# Rails Flash Message -> We're sorry , but something went wrong

Tags: ruby-on-rails, flash, message

I have an issue with the rails flash message ,

until now my application runs great but when I want to use flash messages like this :

```
redirect_to @post, notice: "Post has been created"
```

or

```
flash[:notice] = "Post has been created"
redirect_to @post
```

My application doesnt run anymore and I have : we're sorry but something went wrong

Have tried many things but still the same issue

Thank you for your help

Comment: Its a common message when you get error in rails. You need to check your log for the error's backtrace. And hopefully you would find the root cause of the error and your something went wrong message would be gone

Comment: Please add your application server log.

Comment: In development.log I have : 
    Started GET "/" for 10.0.2.2 at 2015-04-06 09:47:30 +0000
        Cannot render console from 10.0.2.2! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
      [1m[36mActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (10.4ms)[0m  [1mSELECT `schema_migrations`.* FROM `schema_migrations`[0m

Comment: In /var/log I have no apache repertory